# Auto-capitalise lone "i" in LaTeX

Tags: macros, automation, capitalization

Is there a package or pre-amble command which would auto-capitalise all lone 'i's within the text of a LaTeX document (i use overleaf to compile)?

I find it easier to write text without manually capitalising the i's, so am looking to avoid having to do this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document? Please advise.

Comment: I can not answer, but would it not be better to correct the error instead of patching it. Most editors can do regex search and replace.

Comment: In Vim, for example, to replace word-initial i followed by space or punctuation: `:%s/\<i\([,\.!?\- ]\)/I\1/gc`

Comment: You have had an answer but you have neither accepted it or explained what is your problem with it.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. @Peter Wilson, I haven't yet had chance to trial these answers due to competing pressures, I'm sorry if this is unacceptable. Once I have trialled them, I will comment again. Thank You for your suggestions colleagues. –

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It provides

1. A Lua function called `lone_i` that does most of the work (by using Lua's powerful `gsub` string function)
2. Two utility LaTeX macros, `\LoneIActivate` and `\LoneIDeactivate`, that activate and deactivate the Lua function.

By "activation", I mean assignment of the function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, where it acts as pre-processor on the input stream, i.e., *before* TeX gets to do its usual processing.

The function `lone_i` finds instances of "lone" `i` characters in the middle of an input string as well as at the very beginning and the very end of an input string.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} %  for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function lone_i ( s )
   s = s:gsub ( "%si%s" , " I " ) -- lone "i" in interior of line
   s = s:gsub ( "^i%s"  , "I "  ) -- at start of line
   s = s:gsub ( "%si$"  , " I"  ) -- at end of line
   return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\LoneIActivate{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "process_input_buffer", lone_i, "LoneI" )}}
\newcommand\LoneIDeactivate{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
  "process_input_buffer", "LoneI" )}}
\begin{document}
%% before activation
i see you

do i see you

see you or i

i i  i  i i 

\medskip
\LoneIActivate

i see you

do i see you

see you or i

i i  i  i i

\end{document}
```